# How to model bind a class that implements an interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The model binding worked fine until i implemented interfaces on top of the following classes:

```
public class QuestionAnswer : IQuestionAnswer
    {

        public Int32 Row_ID { get; set; }
        public Int32 Column_ID { get; set; }
        public String Value { get; set; }

    }

    public class HiddenAnswer : IHiddenAnswer
    {

        public Int32 Hidden_Field_ID { get; set; }
        public String Hidden_Field_Value { get; set; }

    }

    public class SurveyAnswer : ISurveyAnswer
    {

        public string SessionID { get; set; }

        public List<IQuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswerList { get; set; }

        public List<IHiddenAnswer> HiddenAnswerList { get; set; }

        public SurveyAnswer()
        {
            QuestionAnswerList = new List<IQuestionAnswer>();
            HiddenAnswerList = new List<IHiddenAnswer>();
        }
    }
```

Now that the interfaces are there, i get a `500 (Internal Server Error)`

The javascript that i use to model bind is the following:

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function () {

            var answers = new Array();
            var hiddenfields = new Array();

            var formname = "#" + $("#formname").val();

            $(':input', formname).each(function () {

                if ($(this).is(":text") || $(this).is(":radio") || $(this).is(":checkbox")) 
                {
                    var answerObject = {
                        Column_ID: $(this).attr('data-column_id'),
                        Row_ID: $(this).attr('data-row_id'),
                        Value: $(this).attr('data-theValue')
                    };

                    answers.push(answerObject);
                }

                else if($(this).is(":hidden")) {
                    var hiddenObject = 
                    {
                        Hidden_Field_ID: $(this).attr('data-hidden_field_id'),
                        Hidden_Field_Value: $(this).attr('data-hidden_field_value')
                    }

                    hiddenfields.push(hiddenObject);
                }
            });

            $('textarea', formname).each(function () {
                var answerObject = {
                    Column_ID: $(this).attr('data-column_id'),
                    Row_ID: $(this).attr('data-row_id'),
                    Value: $(this).val(),
                };

                answers.push(answerObject);
            });

            var allAnswers = {
                SessionID: 0,
                QuestionAnswerList: answers,
                HiddenAnswerList: hiddenfields
            }

            postForm(allAnswers);
        });
```

The Controller Action looks like this:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult SubmitSurvey(SurveyAnswer answers)
        {
            // Dette tillader CORS
            Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            bc.SaveSurvey(answers);

            return null;
        }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How is your controller action look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> what am i doing wrong?

You cannot expect the model binder to know that when it encounters the `IQuestionAnswer` interface on your `SurveyAnswer` view model it should use the `QuestionAnswer` type. It's nice that you have declared this implementation of the interface but the model binder has no clue about it.

So you will have to write a custom model binder for the `IQuestionAnswer` interface (same for the `IHiddenAnswer` interface) and indicate which implementation do you want to be used:

```
public class QuestionAnswerModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var type = typeof(QuestionAnswer);
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
        return model;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in your `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IQuestionAnswer), new QuestionAnswerModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answers as usual :) I have implemented the custom model binders and it works. When you add the custom model binder it has to be typeof(IQuestionAnswer) and typeof(IHiddenAnswer) in order to work.