# ViewModel not posting back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, postback

I have this in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModels = _dataSyncService.Get().Select(provider => new IndexViewModel
    {
        Selected = false, Provider = provider
    }).ToList();

    return View(viewModels);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<IndexViewModel> viewModels)
{
    //Breakpoint on this to check viewModels
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public IDataSyncProvider Provider { get; set; }
}
```

And my Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <button type="submit" class="btn blue">Trigger Selected</button>

    @foreach (var sync in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(s => sync.Selected)
            </td>
            <td>@sync.Provider.FriendlyName</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

But my models are posted back, `viewModels` always comes back as null. I read alot about having to assign Id's to the check box etc but I thought that's what `Html.CheckBoxFor` is for.

I'm sure I'll be kicking myself about this at some point but I could do with some guidance please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the built in Html helpers like `Html.CheckBoxFor` then you need to use a `for` loop instead of the `foreach` in order to the helpers render the correct input names:

```
@for(int sync = 0; sync < Model.Count; sync++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[sync].Selected)
        </td>
        <td>@Model[sync].Provider.FriendlyName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

You can read more about binding to lists here: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: Ah, examples I have seen do it that way but I thought that was just their preference. I'll give it a go.

Comment: This is not a preference. If you want to bind to collection the input names has to follow a scheme as discrebed in the linked article. And the helpers only generate this names if you are using an array indexer inside them. So you can still use a `foreach` if you maintain a separate index and use the indexer in the helpers, but in this case the `foreach` does not buy you anything so it easier to go with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Excellent, this has sorted the postback now (i.e Selected = true when ticked and posted back) however the `Provider` part of my ViewModel isn't posting back. Do you know why? I've tried adding `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Provider)` but that didn't seem to help. p.s I've checked the ViewModel when it's assigned to the view and it's being sent Ok.

Comment: The `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Provider)` only would work if your `Provider` is a simple type. For complex types you have to list all its properties so something like `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Provider.Prop1) @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Provider.Prop2)` etc. But the MVC model binding DOES not support binding to interfaces out of the box. So even if you specify the properties it won't work. You need to write your own custom model binder which can bind your `IDataSyncProvider` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812880/how-to-model-bind-a-class-that-implements-an-interface

Answer (score -1):

This is because, you are just redirecting it using return RedirectToAction("Index");

In your POST action

try :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<IndexViewModel> viewModels)
{
    return View(viewModels); 
}
```

Hope will help.

Comment: I've edited my post as it obviusly wasn't clear. I have a breakpoint on that part and am checking the `viewModels` variable before the redirect.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's problem as also stated in the comments the `return RedirectToAction` code was just an example.